# Running a command with root priviliges without SUDO and not as root user

Tags: shell, permissions, sudo, root

How can you run a command (e.g. iftop or similar) that requires root privileges from a non-root user and **without** using SUDO in front?

Alternatively, how can you give root privileges to a user without becoming root?

Ideally, I want to run the iftop command in the following way:

```
[user@pc]$ iftop
```

And **not** like:

```
[user@pc]$ sudo iftop

[root@pc]$ iftop
```

Comment: What is the purpose ? Sounds like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I cannot run my command as root nor with sudo. So I'm looking for alternatives

Comment: @Adam Why can't you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can you run a command (e.g. iftop or similar) that requires root
>     privileges from a non-root user and without using SUDO in front?

There are at least 2 methods you can use to allow
non-root users use iftop but both of them require root access.

The safer method is to assign `cap_net_raw` capability to iftop binary:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep "$(command -v iftop)"
```

The less safe method is to assign setuid root:

```
sudo chmod +s "$(command -v iftop)"
```

> Alternatively, how can you give root privileges to a user without becoming root?

You can't.

Comment: If I add the root setuid, the iftop command will be run with the root user, right? 

The best solution for me would be to run a generic binary that requires root privileges but from a non-root user and without sudo.

Comment: @Adam this sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: It is only for testing purposes, not for production. In any case, is it possible?

Comment: @Adam: yes, it will. *The best solution for me would be to run a generic binary that requires root privileges but from a non-root user and without sudo.* - why do you need that? If there is a binary you use very often and get tired always typing *sudo* first the safest way is to assign needed capabilities with `setcap`, you will not sudo any more. Remember it's a huge security risk to allow unprivileged users on the system to run binaries that should run as root.

Comment: @Adam: I hope you're at least doing that in a virtual machine or a container and that you're the only user of that system. If that's your situation, you're free to experiment.

Comment: @Adam: although in that situation couldn't you simply log in as root?

Comment: Yes, I'm running in a VM and I'm the only user. I'm testing whether I can run some binaries that require root without sudo and without logging as root. I will try with "setcap". Thanks!

Comment: @Adam: If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using the set user id file attribute:

```
# chmod u+s /usr/bin/sleep
# sleep 1000&
# ps aux | grep -w sleep | grep -v grep
root   1234  0.0  0.0   ...  0:00 sleep 1000
```

THIS IS A BIG SECURITY RISK!

If you wish to run something as someone else (not `root`, as here), that is possible:

```
# chown pulse /usr/bin/sleep
# chmod u+s /usr/bin/sleep
# sleep 1000&
# ps aux | grep -w sleep | grep -v grep
pulse   1234  0.0  0.0   ...  0:00 sleep 1000
```

If you are not root you can allow someone else to run a command as you:

```
# id -nu
john
# ls -l a.out
-rwxr-x--- 1 john users   50923 Mar 25 10:17 a.out
# chmod go+rx,u+s a.out
# ls -l a.out
-rwsr-xr-x 1 john users   50923 Mar 25 10:17 a.out
```

(please note the "s" where the "x" was in "rwx...". That means the set user id flag is set)

Then, as `jane`:

```
# id -nu
jane
# ~john/a.out
```

That command `a.out` will be run as `john`.

Comment: First, it's `/usr/bin/sleep`. Second, how can you do that as non-root?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Thanks for pointing out the typo. I have corrected it and added an example as non-root. None of the involved users need to be `root`.  Naturally, you need to set the flag as the person who is to be impersonated and on your own file.  Otherwise there would be no security in Linux.

Comment: OP asked `how can you give root privileges to a user without becoming root? `.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Then the second part of my comment has the answer.