# How to write a script that edits brightness file in /sys/class/backlight/ideapad/?

Tags: scripting, i3, brightness

I am using i3 wm and I've got my brightness file in `/sys/class/backlight/ideapad/brightness`.

```
╰─$ ls -la /sys/class/backlight/ideapad/

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 18 16:55 brightness
```

When I want to change the brightness (say to 4) I do:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/ideapad/brightness"
```

I would like to write a script that would increase or decrease the brightness by 1 and then bind that script to some key combination in i3 wm config file (`CTRL+F1` for example) so that I can control the brightness by pressing keys instead of editing the brightness file manually every time I want to change the brightness.

Since this requires root privilege, I am not sure how to achieve that. Should I change my user as the owner of the `brightness` file or should I just change the group of the file? Or any other way you can think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`/sys` is a RAM based virtual file system](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt), so changing the permission of its files will not survive a reboot.

### Option 1: [Acpilight](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/acpilight/)

The only package solution that has ever worked for me.

> On some modern laptops "XRandR" might lack the ability to set the display brightness. This capability was moved/unified to the kernel's ACPI interface, via `/sys/class/backlight/`.
>
> "acpilight" provides a drop-in replacement for the `xbacklight` command that uses the ACPI interface instead of "XRandR", allowing old scripts to run. As a result, `xbacklight` can subsequently be used also from the console and Wayland (X11 is not used at all).

Although few distributions have it in their repositories, you can always compile and install it yourself. Then just use

```
xbacklight +10
```

to increase brightness by 10%.

---

**For options 2 and 3, replace `ideapad` by the appropriate path component in your system.**
`intel_backlight` and `acpi_video0` are common ones.

### Option 2: Udev

Make sure `video` is in the output of `groups` command. If not, add your user to that group.

Then create a Udev rules file with `sudo -e /etc/udev/rules.d/backlight.rules`. Contents:

```
RUN+="/bin/chgrp video /sys/class/backlight/ideapad/brightness"
RUN+="/bin/chmod 0664  /sys/class/backlight/ideapad/brightness"
```

Reboot. Thanks to: [Fistrosan at Arch Linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1935565#p1935565).

### Option 3.1: C + setuid

This C program is the solution I have written some time ago and has never failed
me. It requires nothing a standard Linux system does not have besides a C compiler.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFSIZE 10

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *fp;
  char scurr[BUFSIZE];
  long new, curr, incr, min = 10;

  /* An argument with an integer increment must be supplied */
  if (argc != 2 || (incr = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10)) == 0) { return(1); }

  /* Retrieve the current brightness and increment it in the brightness file */
  if ((fp = fopen("/sys/class/backlight/ideapad/brightness", "r+")) 
      && fgets(scurr, BUFSIZE, fp)) {
    curr = strtol(scurr, NULL, 10);
    rewind(fp);
    new = curr + incr;
    if (new < min) { new = min; }
    fprintf(fp, "%ld\n", new);
    fclose(fp);
  } else { return(2); }

  return(0);
}
```

Compile it (`br.c` is the file name, `br` the executable), make root the owner, turn on the [setuid bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#When_set_on_an_executable_file) and put the executable
somewhere in your `PATH` (`/usr/local/bin/` is a typical choice).

```
cc br.c -o br
chown root br
chmod u+s  br
mv br /usr/local/bin/
```

Now just executing `br -100` decreases your brightness by 100.

See that I have also set the minimum brightness to `min = 10`. That is quite low on my
machine that one barely notices the display is on. Tweak that value according to your
needs.

### Option 3.2: C + capabilities

Setuid gives `br` full root rights. If you want to be very cautious and give it only the necessary priviledge set — namely, to bypass file permission checking —, substitute the `chown` and `chmod` lines above by [the appropriate capability](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)

```
setcap cap_dac_override+ep br
```

Comment: Writing a C program just to be able to change brightness? It's good
nobody suggested recompiling the kernel. udev is the way to go
here. You could also mention that setuid root is discouraged in favor
of fine-grained capabilities(7). It's nice to know desktop Linux
developers are doing everything they can to keep their market
share. Everything is going in the right direction 

Comment: @Quasímodo: Capabilities are better because they are fine-grained - instead of
allowing a buggy binary to do everything as root you can only allow it
to execute a certain set of actions - see for example my answer
[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/574888/72304)

Comment: @Quasímodo: Archwiki also explains that well https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/capabilities

Comment: Very thorough answer.  If you do decide to compile the C program, make sure you update "ideapad" in fopen to match your system

Answer (score 1):

Changing group ownership is usually the way to go but notice that
you'll have to do it each time after reboot. To do this automatically
create udev rule as described at [Arch
wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#ACPI):

> By default, only root can change the brightness by this method. To
> allow users in the video group to change the brightness, a udev rule
> such as the following can be used:
>
> /etc/udev/rules.d/backlight.rules
>
> ```
> ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", KERNEL=="acpi_video0", GROUP="video", MODE="0664"
> ```

If you're not a member of `video` group add your user to it:

```
sudo gpasswd video -a $(whoami)
```

Notice that you have log out and log back in to refresh group
membership information:

```
su -l $(whoami)
```

Check if you're a member of `video` group with id, it should print
something like:

```
$ id
uid=1000(ja) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),16(dialout),17(audio),18(video),83(plugdev),215(vboxusers),281(docker)
```

Of course, you can use any group that your user is a member of in
udev rule, not necessarily `video`.

Comment: I guess I should create the `video` group first and then add my group, right?

Comment: Check if you're already a member of this group with `id`. Of course, you can use a different group.

Comment: Oh I am not a member of the `video` group. I didn't know the group `video` already exists.

Comment: @AndréYuhai: see updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the details! One last question though, do I need to change the group of the `brightness` file as well after creating the `udev` rule?

Comment: No, the whole of adding the udev rule is for permissions to be changed automatically by udev.

Comment: I've done as you said and added my user to the video group and then added this `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", KERNEL=="ideapad", GROUP="video", MODE="0664"` udev rule to `/etc/udev/rules.d/backlight.rules`. However, I still get `Permission denied` when I try `echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/ideapad/brightness`.

Comment: Run `sudo udevadm trigger` and check if permissions changed.

Comment: I still get permission denied error when I want to write to the brightness file. By the way `ideapad` is a symlink. Does that change anything somehow?

Comment: It shouldn't. Post output of `ls -Alh /sys/class/backlight`

Comment: Here it is: https://paste.ofcode.org/LecGMGg3XDyWd6nhhLq6bt

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a laptop here to check. You can check if correct parameters are used in udev rule using `udevadm info -a -p  /sys/class/backlight/ideapad` and if rule is fired at all using `udevadm test /sys/class/backlight/ideapad`

Comment: I think everything works correctly, I've tried the commands and here is the output of each: https://paste.ofcode.org/Xh8qXypVMckDBAq6F9rBUd