# Awesome Doesn't Know My Brightness Ajustment Buttons

Tags: debian, awesome, brightness, keyboard-backlight

After installing [Awesome](https://awesomewm.org/) (with no other GUI environments), the function keys on my laptop (for brightness especially), don't work like they do when I install KDE or GNOME.

So far, the only method I've found to control brightness is commands like this:

```
echo "10" > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
echo "20" > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
echo "30" > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
echo "40" > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
echo "50" > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
echo "60" > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
echo "70" > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
echo "80" > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
echo "90" > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
echo "100" > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
```

However, I cannot easily automate these commands to hot-keys because they only work as root. Surprisingly, sudo doesn't even work when using my regular user account. For example, this doesn't work:

```
sudo echo "60" > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
```

The above command outputs: `Permission denied`. So, as is, to change brightness I have to `su` first. Perhaps someone can explain how I can permit my regular user account to modify that path without escalation. Then, I'd be able to tie hotkeys to these brightness adjustments.

Ideally, though, I suspect that there is a package I can install that would map my laptop's existing keys for brightness adjustment. Here's the model (if that helps you know the package):

```
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: System76 product: Bonobo WS v: bonw13
           Mobo: System76 model: Bonobo WS v: bonw13
```

Comment: `sudo echo "60" > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness` ... only the `echo` command runs with elevated privileges ... google `linux exec`

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/625144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try `brightnessctl`;
`apt install brightnessctl`

`brightnessctl g` to get the current brightness
`brightnessctl -l` to get more elaborate info on current brightness
`brightnessctl s {integer or percentage}` to set brightness
`brightnessctl -d acpi_video0 set {integer or percentage}` specify the device to set brightness. The device can be located in the elaborate info. I believe you'll locate which device is needed to be set, ie on my laptop radeon or acpi.

After you locate the proper command, assign it to a function key or wherever else you like.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was really aggravating me.

Comment: To emphasize how much I appreciate your suggestion, I had to come back here and thank you again. I wrote a [python script in autokey](https://i.imgur.com/Q6bhf6J.png) that maps this to alt+b. Now, I'm always a hotkey away from setting brightness to my desired level. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Xorg, you can use the `xbacklight` program to adjust laptop brightness.

Get current brightness: `xbacklight -get`
Set specific brightness: `xbacklight -set <percentage>`
Increase brightness by increments: `xbacklight -inc <percentage>`
Decrease brightness by increments: `xbacklight -dec <percentage>`

It does not require root privileges and can be easily mapped to hotkeys.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already tried `xbacklight`, but no matter which arguments I try with xbacklight, the output is always `No outputs have backlight property`. I'm pretty sure this 4K laptop monitor does have a backlight, so I'm not sure why xbacklight can't detect it.

Comment: It might be related to whether or not the RandR extension is loaded (you can check with `xdpyinfo | grep RANDR`) and also how the NVIDIA GPU is interacting with the extension, if at all. I have not seen that issue with integrated Intel GPUs. Unfortunately, I do not have a laptop with an NVIDIA GPU to test.